# How to recover a Domain Controller after disabling and reenabling File and Printer Sharing?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, domain-controller

In an attempt to improve the security of my Windows Server 2008 R2 with Exchange 2010 SP3, I decided to test if File and Printer Sharing was really important to allow Exchange to work (thats all I really need from this server).

When I did, I ruined the server. Reenabling it don't seem to undo the mess.

After a reboot, Windows Explorer refuses to initialize. I'm limited to commands, some parts of Control Panel hang when I try to access them. I rebooted the server again, and now it doesn't even go past "Applying computer settings..."

I have no idea what to do, Google doesn't seem to help. Is it possible that I'm the only animal who ever tried to disable File and Printer Sharing in a domain controller?

How can I recover from this situation?

Note: I can access the shared folders from other network computers.

Comment: Backup? You DO have made one, or? It is like basline since - hm - 1955 or so ;)

Comment: Yeah I have an image but its pretty ancient, I'm not confident its a viable option.

Comment: Have you tried Domain Services Restore Mode?

Comment: Sorry, you say you have Exchange problems but also mention domain controllers. Is your Exchange server also a DC?

Comment: DSRM, which is **Directory** Services Restore Mode is simply Safe Mode with Directory Services disabled, to allow for an authoritative restore of AD from backup media. On its own, it does nothing.

Comment: Yes, its one server responsible for everything.

Comment: That's really bad practice. You should migrate away from this ASAP.

Comment: Its inviable. Its a really small environment, all I really need is Exchange, but unfortunately I can't cut the AD crap and just have it. If it was my call I would just have Linux with postfix. This freaking Windows Server is like minesweeper, if you do anything wrong it goes streight down the toilet.

Comment: file and printer sharing is not necessary to exchange and removing them should not have the slightest effect on whether or not windows boots. Removing or adding roles is a standard function and something which is done constantly on servers. Can you give an idea of what other modifications you made to the system?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that windows comes with its own backup software which works extremely well. Its also essential to backup an exchange server as exchange has a transactional log, like sql servers, which is only purged after doing a backup.

Comment: Also, if you don't have a second AD controller, this config can cause problems on reboot. When Exchange AD Topology service goes to shut down, it tries to talk to a DC.  If it's on the only DC, well.  The AD services shut down first (alphabetical), so it spins for awhile saying, "Bueller?  Bueller?" and then crashes.  So if your shutdowns take half an hour, that's why.

Comment: @IanMurphy Yeah, I used this thing once to transfer my server to a new machine, and when I tried to restore the backup to the new server, with same name, same domain, same version of everything, it refused to, saying the backup belonged to a different server (something related to database serial number). I had to restore the mailboxes of my users by exporting them one by one to .PST using Outlook. It was a massive disappointment and a pain in the ass.

Comment: @IanMurphy Do you know where I can read about how to use this backup tool reliably, keeping in mind I have only one server in my domain?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: its trivially easy to use. You need to add the characteristic to windows as its not installed by default (server manager). You need a usb drive to dedicate to the backup. Connect it, run windows backup (type backup after clicking on start to find it), create a new backup job and tell it to backup your c: and, say, D: drives but exclude the backup drive. Tell it to use the backup drive as destination. It will format the disk. thats it. the rest is automatic. You can have multiple usb disks and use them on different days.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say for certain based on the information you've provided, but I doubt that disabling and enabling file and print killed your server.  I think it's far more likely that the server already had issues (bad hard drive?) and the reboots finished it off.

Your hardware vendor probably has diagnostics that will enable you to check the hard drives/RAID.  That should be the first place you look.  Correct any errors there before proceeding further.

Since you said in the comments above that your backups are ancient (ouch), assuming your storage tests clean and/or the RAID is repaired, you're probably going to have to attempt a repair install of Windows and hope for the best.  (If it's a single disk, well.  Ouch.)

Once you get your server back up, please implement a backup strategy.  Do it for your future self, because hardware fails and there *will* be a next time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a "Boot with last valid configuration" and to my surprise it fixed the problem. I know this option is mostly useless with Domain Controllers, because it won't recover configuration of the Active Directory metadata, but aparently I got lucky with this one.

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able.

Comment: Time to implement backups!